# CMD/Batch extract each text file line and loop from variable

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, text-files

I have this code

```
@Echo Off 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
SET mydir=D:\ 
SET DirCount=2 
SET T=
For /F %%i In (qqq.txt) Do (  
  set fg=%%i 
  FOR /L %%G IN (2, 1, %DirCount%) DO (call :subroutine "%%i") 
)

:subroutine 
Set T=!T!../ 
start /wait %mydir%program.exe %T%%fg% 
echo %t%%fg%  >>%cd%see.log
```

qqq.txt has rows

```
1
2
3
```

In result i get:

```
../1
../../2
../../../3
../../../../3
```

But I need like this:

```
../1
../../1
../2
../../2
../3
../../3
```

Please Help what I'm doing wrong?

---

Just a little additional requried

I need what first ocur in

```
set "T=!T!../"
will be without dots
set "T=!T!/"
result must be
/1
../1
../../1
/2
../2
../../2
```

how and where to add counter and make visible for each loop somthing like

```
echo Now looping: %%i row of %countrow(in qqq.txt), left %countrow-%%I
echo Now looping: Dir Nr%%G !T!%%i
```

Sorry for stupid questions but batch coding is difficult to me.

Comment: Regarding the updated question - Getting the number of rows in a file is not intuitive, so I'll add that to my answer. But for the remainder you should think about your problem some more. Most of what you are asking deals with simple logic. If you were able to write your original code, then you should be able to solve most of the new qestions on your own. Hint - you just need a trivial change to the accepted answer - modify the DirCount value and move the location of the line `Set T=!T!../`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 problems:

1) You don't exit your program after the main loop so it falls through into the subroutine

2) Your FOR /L IN() clause is wrong, the first number should be 1, not 2

3) You need to reset T back to undefined within the outer loop.

***EDIT***
 
I believe you may have an additional problem. When redirecting output you prefix your file name with `%cd%`. I don't think that is giving the result you want. If your current directory is `C:\test`, then `>>%cd%see.log` will result in output sent to file named `testsee.log` in the root `C:\` directory. If you wanted the output in the current directory then it should be `>>%cd%\see.log`, but the path info is not really needed since the default is to use the current directory. So really all you would need is `>>see.log`. Since I don't know your intent, I have left the redirection as originally written. ***End Edit***

```
@echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET mydir=D:\
SET DirCount=2
For /F %%i In (qqq.txt) Do (
  SET T=
  set fg=%%i
  FOR /L %%G IN (1, 1, %DirCount%) DO (call :subroutine "%%i")
)
exit /b

:subroutine
Set T=!T!../
start /wait %mydir%program.exe %T%%fg%
echo %t%%fg%  >>%cd%see.log
```

There is no need to call a subroutine in your case, especially since you have already enabled delayed expansion. The following gives the same result with less code, and it is faster because it avoids the relatively slow CALL statement. *(performance is probably not an issue in this small example, but if using loops with many iterations it can make a huge difference)*

```
@echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET mydir=D:\
SET DirCount=2
For /F %%i In (qqq.txt) Do (
  SET "T="
  FOR /L %%G IN (1, 1, %DirCount%) DO (
    set "T=!T!../"
    start /wait %mydir%program.exe !T!%%i
    echo !T!%%i  >>%cd%see.log
  )
)
```

***Partial answer to additional questions***

You can use FOR /F to capture the result of FIND /C to get the number of lines in "qqq.txt". This should be done before you enter the main loop:

```
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<qqq.txt') do set "rowCount=%%N"
```

You can use SET /A to do basic math, thus enabling you to keep track of the number of remaining lines

First initialize the remaining count before entering the main loop:

```
set "remainingLines=%rowCount%"
```

Then within the main loop use SET /A to decrement the value.

```
set /a remainingLines-=1
```

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - I may have found an additional problem. See the new section marked *EDIT* in my answer.

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - I've partially answered your additional questions. The rest is up to you :-)